# Missing menu in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I installed the Reporting Services on my personal laptop. After running on the web Portal URL, I do not see the Branding menu. I'm logging with the admin user And I'm not the Power BI Desktop in setting menu I installed the Express version and my SSms edition is Standard Edition. what can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure of what is your current setup **BUT**

Setup needed :

- SQL Server
- Power BI Report Server (Superset of SQL Server Reporting Services)

And then on your server, the branding menu will be accesible with admin rights.

Read [this useful link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/branding-the-web-portal?view=sql-server-2017).